# Spark Elasticsearch basic tuning

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

How to setup spark for speed?

I'm running spark-elasticsearch to analyze log data.

It takes about 5min to do aggregate/join with 2million rows (4gig).

I'm running 1 master, 3 workers on 3 machines. 
I increased executor memory to 8g, increased ES nodes from 1 to 3.

I'm running standalone clusters in client mode (https://becominghuman.ai/real-world-python-workloads-on-spark-standalone-clusters-2246346c7040)
I'm not using spark-submit, just running python code after launching master/workers

Spark seems to launch 3 executors total (which are from 3 workers).

I'd like to tune spark a little bit to get the most performance with little tuning..

Which way should I take for optimization?

> 1. consider other cluster (yarn, etc .. although I have no idea what they offer, but it seems it's easier to change memory related settings
>      there)
> 2. run more executors
> 3. analyze the job plan with `explain` api
> 4. accept it takes that much time because you have to download 4gig data (should spark grap all data to run aggregate? such as group by
>      and sum), if applicable, save the data to parquet (?) for further
>      analysis

Below are my performance related setting

```
 conf.set("es.scroll.size", 10000)
 conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
 conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "8g")
 conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
 conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
 conf.set("es.nodes.resolve.hostname", "false")
 conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.4.2/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-7.4.2.jar")
 conf.set("es.nodes", settings.ES_HOST)
 conf.set("es.nodes.wan.only", 'true')
```

spark-defaults.conf

```
 # https://becominghuman.ai/real-world-python-workloads-on-spark-standalone-clusters-2246346c7040
 spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled true

 # https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation
 spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
 spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always a matter of memory or cluster configuration, I would suggest starting by trying to optimize the query/aggregation you're running before increasing memory.

You can find here some hints for [Spark Performance Tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html). See also [Tuning Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html). Make sure the query is optimal and avoid known bad performance as UDFs.

For executor and memory configuration in your cluster, you have to take into consideration the available memory and cores on all machines to calculate the adequate parameters. Here is an [intersting post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/) on best practices.